# Object-oriented style programming for Java

Tags: java, oop

I have been working on an XML parser for a few days now, and have been working in `main` for mostly the entire project. The code is starting to get cluttered, and I have some questions.

```
// Initializes the xPath objects for XML parsing use
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

XPathExpression hourly = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/time-layout[3]/start-valid-time/text()"); // Time tri-hourly. Parses in the third time-layout, as this is the time information we need
XPathExpression tempHourly = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/parameters/temperature[@type='hourly']/value/text()"); // Temperature tri-hourly. Parses in through the 'hourly' temperature attribute
XPathExpression dewPoint = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/parameters/temperature[@type='dew point']/value/text()"); // Dew point tri-hourly. Parses in through the 'dew point' temperature attribute
XPathExpression windSpeed = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/parameters/wind-speed[@type='sustained']/value/text()"); // Sustained wind speed tri-hourly. Parses in through the 'sustained' wind-speed attribute
XPathExpression relHum = xpath.compile("/dwml/data/parameters/humidity[@type='relative']/value/text()"); // Relative humidity tri-hourly. Parses in through the 'relative' humidity attribute

// Casting the objects to NodeLists
NodeList hourlyResult = (NodeList) hourly.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList tempHourlyResult = (NodeList) tempHourly.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList dewPointResult = (NodeList) dewPoint.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET); 
NodeList windSpeedResult = (NodeList) windSpeed.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList relHumResult = (NodeList) relHum.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Working in main, I had no worries about object-oriented programming, however, I would really like to change these to `static` or `public` variables. Could someone show me the correct way to do this, object-oriented style?

Comment: What functions do you have now? In general terms, get those functions who usually share a common parameter (they usually get the parameter, work with it, and call other functions sending the same parameter) and make them methods in a class, where the parameter would be an instance variable (a field). You may end up with several classes - don't worry about that, if your system has several responsibilities, it is better to have each of them in a separate class than cluttering them all into one.

Comment: `static` and `public` variables might just be the least OOP-style of variables there are. They violate encapsulation.

Comment: @Ingo At the moment, yes. You know what? I'll change that.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Could you explain further? I know `static` violates a lot of things, but, argh, it's so convenient to use.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of your code? Like when people use your code, what do you want them to be able to do? It looks like you want to take an XML document and return the data in it as lists. Is that true?

Comment: @Vidya Yep. It takes a URL of XML outputs and uses XPath to parse that XML.

Comment: Well to start with, find structures of data that just fit together logically (just like 'firstname' and 'lastname'): they'll define your 'domain' classes. Then, get domain driven: if your domain class can answer 'questions' about the data it contains, well this defines your API and your different implementations should be there. Objects talk to each other (just like 'Small Talk') and ask questions. This way your code becomes more maintainable. Encapsulation is the main stuff to understand for OOP.

Comment: @zenbeni I am thinking `XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();` can be turned into a constructor, however, instead of using the `new XPathFactory()` structure, it uses the `.newInstance()` method on the `XPathFactory` object. Not sure how I can proceed knowing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, there are many ways you could do this. I am going to provide a skeleton that provides one option. I will not deal with performance or the vagaries of XPath processing. This is meant to illustrate an idea for class design.

Consider a class dedicated to processing an XML document:

```
class XMLProcessor { //By the way, that is a terrible name, but I will let you deal with that.
  private static final String HOURS_XPATH = "/dwml/data/time-layout[3]/start-valid-time/text()";
  private XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  private XPathExpression hourly;

  public XMLProcessor(String url) {
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath(); 
    hourly = xpath.compile(HOURS_XPATH); 
  }   

  public List<String> getHours() {
    //Pass hourly to toNodeList and turn it to an ArrayList
    //Provide similar methods for all the other data sets you want to extract and provide
  }

  private NodeList toNodeList(XPathExpression exp) {
    //to be reused for all the conversions
    return (NodeList) exp.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
  }
}
```

Then in `main` you just do something like

```
XMLProcessor x = new XMLProcessor(url);
List<String> = x.getHours();
```

Note that the client, `main` in this case, has no idea that `XMLProcessor` is doing anything related to XPaths. It passes a URL and gets non-XML related data back. The client doesn't care and shouldn't know what the data format is or how it's processed.

Note also how I am returning a `List` rather than `ArrayList`. Your client shouldn't even know which `List` implementation was used.

Note *also* how you probably want to inject your XPaths through some kind of configuration rather than hardcoded.

Again, this is not meant to be ideal or performant, and it may not actually do what you want. But hopefully it gives you some ideas about how to structure your code from an OO perspective.

Comment: Awesome! This template will help me out a ton for future projects. Thanks for the reply =). I am in the process of restructuring my old project and learning a thing or two on the way, so this will be forever useful.

Comment: I believe you meant `XPathFactory` instead of `PathFactory` here: `private PathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();`?

Comment: Indeed so. I am the master of typos. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the answer. Glad this helps you. Good luck with your project and OO!